# Open every text file in directory then replace particular line in each

Tags: python

I have some code that will iterate through every file in a directory, but what I need is for each file iterated though a particular line will be replaced with a new value. Can anyone fill in the missing blank for me in the code below?

```
import os

line_old = ''
line_new = ''

for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):

    #something that will work, rather than the below example 
    file.replace(line_old, line_new)
```

Comment: Could you please add some example? You question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) will find all `.txt` files, you can then use [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to loop through the lines of each file and replace the line in the original file with `inplace=True`:

```
line_old = ''
line_new = ''
import fileinput
import sys
import glob

for line in fileinput.input(glob.iglob("/mydir/*.txt"),inplace=True):
    if line.strip() == line_old:
        sys.stdout.write(line_new+"\n")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Or write to a [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to replace the original file:

```
import glob
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
for fle in glob.iglob("./*.txt"):
    with open(fle) as f,NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as temp:
        for line in f:
            if line.rstrip() == line_old:
                temp.write(line_new + "\n")
            else:
                temp.write(line)
        move(temp.name,fle)
```

This presumes you are actually changing a whole line, if you are matching a particular pattern you can use a regex and the logic will be exactly the same, just compile the regex and use `re.sub`

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"\bfoo bar\b")
re.sub(line_old,line_new)
```

Comment: hello again. i used the top section of code in your answer for what i wanted. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(file) as f:
    data = f.read().replace(line_old,line_new)
with open(file,"w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could probably more concise, but it will work.

```
f = open(file,'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open(file,'w')
for line in lines:
    if line_old in line:
        line = line_new
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```